# mysql dynamic table standard

Tags: php, mysql

`$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl as t WHERE t.id = 1';`

in the above statement would it be wrong to do the following?

```
`t`.`id`
```

if yes then whats the correct way by the mysql standards ?

Comment: _would it be wrong to do the following_ what do you mean by _wrong_?

Comment: i meant putting back ticks on the `t` in the where statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ist good in both cases:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl as t WHERE t.id = 1';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl as t WHERE `t`.`id` = 1';
```

the apostrophes are good because the column name could be the same as mysql function name like `FROM` so in that case to prevent error you put the column name into apostrophes

Comment: does mysql recommend it ? or is it your guess (not being rude btw)

Comment: well for example MySQL Workbench render every query using apostrophes everywhere it is possible - because in that case you're sure that there will be no errors - This is standard. people don't use apostrophes often because they are lazy ;)

Comment: cool :) thats nice to know :) it was more of a knowledge question than helpful but thank you m8